# End user site backup

Tags: backup

Now that SharePoint Designer 2010 does not allow end users to make backups of their sites, are there any other options for an end user or site collection administrator to backup or migrate a SharePoint 2010 site/site collection?

Can the `backup-spsite` Powershell cmdlet be used remotely by a site collection administrator, or must all site collection backups be performed by a farm administrator on an actual server in the SharePoint farm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options. For site collection administrators you can backup sites (with content as long as it's under 10mb) by saving the site as a site template. The template will be stored in the root site collection and any SC admin can use it to create a new site on another site collection. Not however this doesn't give you full fidelity as several things (namely permissions) are missing.

You can do PowerShell remotely. It's a complicated setup and does work. Note that the user running the PowerShell commands needs to be granted additional access but that would be assumed.

You can view a step-by-step guide on how to setup remote PowerShell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/opal/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step).

Comment: Agree with Bil above, but stsadm for those old timer SharePoint 2007 people is still doable, or you can be really clever and use the SharePoint .NET API's for your backups.