# powershell backup site cillection

Tags: powershell

I am trying to take a BackUp of a Site Collection from a remote computer, but I am getting a error that i am not sure of the script is

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotecomputername -ScriptBlock {Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://remotecomputername:8080" -Path "C:\Users\username\Documents\SiteBackUp\BackUp8080"} -credential username
```

the error is get is :

The term 'Backup-SPSite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the sp
elling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Backup-SPSite:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Regards, Vikram

Answer (score 1):

You are running the command from powershell:

- use either the sharepoint management shell (under the Sharepoint start menu)
- or load sharepoint in powershell "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" (see: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/fcb77654-0f13-42e0-b181-6e52242fe9d6)
- or in ISE: see: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2010/05/03/adding-sharepoint-2010-poweshell-cmdlets-to-your-powershell-ise.aspx

Comment: The script block doesn't include the pssnapin so this is likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows PowerShell or SharePoint Management Shell?
This is however an old question and here you may find something useful:
[End user site backup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/end-user-site-backup)

Comment: I am using SharePoint Management Shell...